# Can we override the value of SimpleChanges in Angular application?

Tags: angular

I am implementing `breadcrumb` in my web app. and it is based on simple parent child component communication model. When the parent passes the value to the child using **Input()** the child performs the action. When the value is passed to the child component for the first time it works as expected. However, when the same value is passed by the parent again the `SimpleChanges` won't recognize it, since the `prevValue` and `CurrentValue` would be same. My doubt is can we override the `prevValue` of the `SimpleChanges` to **undefined** once we perform the action in the child component so that even when the next time we get same value it is not ignored.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: not sure what you're asking here.  ngOnInit is called when Input vars are initialized, ngOnChanges, when the reference changes thereafter.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that. I'd once faced a similar problem. I solved it by wrapping my value in a simple object that is carrying in addition the current UTC-timestamp. Something like this: `{value: currentValue, timestamp: new Date().getTime()}`. Thus, it‘s always a new 'value' you send and it works even if `value` itself never changes.

Comment: @Lynx Yes, that exactly what I was looking for.. something which works for me even if the value doesn't change.

Comment: You're welcome. 